# Find data and nonce such that the first 6 positions of the SHA256 Value are 0

Tags: python, hash, blockchain, sha

```
block=2
previous_hash=6bdf9382a9e8f99a651251f2a3e8257dd27efdc86069f85ad4a5312c283d379b
data=data={1BTC 0x11001101 to 0x00001011; 1BTC 0x11001101 to 0x00111001}
```

This is the second block I have

Now I have to create a block that uses the hash of this block with random data and nonce such that the block 4 previous_hash starts with 6 zeros

```
block=3
previous_hash=36f57a910443cc75320e3842e351952a446a5f891e387eb394dd895deb5a1d12
data=
nonce=
```

Actually I am trying to find random floats for data and nonce until this has happened any other suggestions?

It's an exercise from college and I guess we literally have to find such data and nonce

Comment: Didn’t they teach you how mining works? You have to write a loop that continuously changes the data and nonce and calculates the sha256 and stops when it finds a solution.

Comment: yeah but isn't there a most efficient method? Tried the usual nonce = nonce+1 for 2 days hahah

Comment: No there isn’t. That’s the whole point of the exercise. It’s hard to mine that is why it makes the whole thing secure. Otherwise people could change data easily.

Comment: If you have any code to share you might be able to mine more efficiently, I suggest you post that and see if anyone can help.